# CLIENT MAC ADDR error on booting via Intel PXE

Tags: boot, vmware, pxe

I'm having a problem with VMware where, when I try to boot any ISO, it always says:

> CLIENT MAC ADDR: 00 0C 29 A9 3A 2E GUID: 564D12D9-E543-62C5-2E3C-35A030A93A
>   PXE-E51: No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received.
>   PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.
>   Operating System not found

I am also booting from an ISO file that VMware recognizes.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The ISO file i have is not on a DVD / flash drive, but rather on my desktop